# Kibana + visualization + timestamp format (YY MMM dd, ddd)

Tags: date, format, kibana

Kibana 7.10.2. Trying to shape @timestamp only for a specific visualization where I would like to have YY MMM dd ddd format (instead of the UTC defined in settings).

Tried using Scripted Fields but it's not working when I use my scripted field in the data histogram visualization.

[Error when using scripted field in visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5al1.png)

[Scripted field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifq4g.png)

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: was your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scripted field such that:

- name: (e.g.) `custom-timestamp`
- language: `painless`
- type: `date`
- format: `Date`
- format pattern: `YY MMM d, ddd`
- Script: `doc['@timestamp'].value`

[image]

Comment: Hi @glenacota!
I tried that but it didn't change anything in the actual visualization (X axis). Date still shows with "2021-04-03" format.